# vk_api python: переименовывание чата

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, asyncio

написал скрипт чтобы он менял название чата на указаное когда не является им. Но что то идет не так и он тупо переименовывает всегда

**main.py:**

```
import vk_api
import asyncio
import time 

token = 'вк токен'

async def get_name(api, chat_id):
    while True:
        name = api.messages.getChat(chat_id=chat_id, fields="nickname")
        time.sleep(3)
        return name 

def rename(api, chat_id, title):
    api.messages.editChat(chat_id=chat_id, title=title)


async def main():
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
    api = vk_session.get_api()
    try:
        while True:
            if await get_name(api, chat_id=921) == '.':
                pass
            elif await get_name(api, chat_id=921) != '.':
                rename(api, chat_id=921, title='.')
            else:
                print(f'123')
    except Exception as i:
        print(i)
        
asyncio.run(main())
```

[image: чат вк]

Comment: А Вы уверены, что `get_name(api, chat_id=921)` возвращает строку с именем, а не null, объект, ошибку и т.п?

Answer (score 0):

функция *get_name* возращает словарь с данными

нужно получить заговолок (title)

```
async def get_name(api, chat_id):
    while True:
        name = api.messages.getChat(chat_id=chat_id, fields='title')
        name = name["title"]
        time.sleep(1)
        return name
```

вывод: 'Привет!' (это название чата)